# yes/ No Is $T$ is linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given  $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be transformation defined by $T(x,y)= (x+1,y+1)$.

Now my question is that Is $T$ is linear transformation ?

My attempt : The main concept of linear transformation is  that $T= 0$, so if we put $x=y=-1$ then $T=0$

So i think it will be linear transformation

Again from another definition of linear transformation we have

$T(x,y) + T(z,w)= T(x+ z, y + w)$

$(x +1 , y+1) + ( z+1 , w +1 ) = ( x+ z+ 1, y+w+1 )$

another Properties also satisfied

so again $T$ is linear transformation

Is its correct or not ?

Comment: $T(0,0)$ is not $(0,0)$, so it's not linear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In order for $T$ to be linear you would have to have$$(x+1,y+1)+(z+1,w+1)=(x+y+1,z+w+1).$$But, in fact,$$(x+1,y+1)+(z+1,w+1)=(x+y+2,z+w+2).$$

And you can just say that $T$ is not linear because $T(0,0)\ne(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

No, $T$ is not linear. Your arithmetic is incorrect, $(x+1)+(z+1)=x+z+2$ so $T$ does not satisfy linearity. You can simply check that by noticing that $T(0,0)\ne (0,0)$; any linear transformation maps zero to zero.

I cannot comment on "the main concept of linear transformation" because what you wrote doesn't really make sense.